# Matching regular expressions with a + and -

Tags: python

Currently working with regular expressions in order to read a file with vertex points. The specific file line that this code is working with is

facet normal -0.000000e+01 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00

My code reads

```
f = open('file.txt')
for line in f:
    e1 = re.findall(
        r'(?<=\w{5}\s\w{6}\s[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1})' #Look ahead
        r'[-+]\d{2}' # Target Point
        r'(?=\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2})', #Look Back
    line)
print(e1)
```

The problem is the Target point

```
       r'[-+]\d{2}' # Target Point
```

This should be matching with +01 however it is not printing out anything. I have tried changing the code in several ways but can't seem to figure it out. I have reread the documentation several times as well but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I tested your regex, and the Target Point regex actually seems to be ok. Your actual problem seems to be that your lookahead regex does not match "facet normal -0.000000e"

Comment: Why don't you simply split the string and let `float()` do the parsing?

Comment: Hey thanks for finding that error I got it working. Out of curiosity how would I let the float do the parsing? Apologies on the late reply.